# Sql server not unique auto-increment column

Tags: sql-server, auto-increment

Let's say I have a table called **[dbo].[Order]** in my MSSQL Server database like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order] (
    [Id]                INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [NumberInMonth]     INT             NOT NULL,
    [Amount]            DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Order] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

I want to have **NumberInMonth** column to be:

- auto-incremented, so that the database will guarantee that the INSERT operation will create a new record with the value of **Number = < previous value of Number > + 1** without any effort on the side of the application code
- not unique, so that i could have one order #18 in January and another one order #18 in February (which will differ by Id field)

And also I'd like to have a way to have a schedulled operation which will reset the counter of **NumberInMonth** every first day of a month

How do I achieve it?

Comment: Which version of sql server?

Comment: @McNets 2016 will work

Comment: Have a look at CREATE SEQUENCE on ms docs.

Comment: If is not useful you could use a INSTEAD OF INSERT or BEFORE INSERT trigger.

Comment: While a SEQUENCE will likely work for you, I would ask *why* you want to do this in the first place? You can easily write a query that will give you this number on the fly.

Comment: Can you create scheduled jobs using sql server agent?

Comment: @DavidG there is a risk of two simultaneous INSERTs into dbo.Order table. I see two options:
1. to get the last number of NumberInMonth using application code and also to lock the table - so that 2 threads will not insert records with the same NumberInMonth value
2. to delegate this job to the database itself.

The second option looks preferable

Comment: @AndreyPesoshin Not with a SEQUENCE there isn't. But you still didn't answer my question - *why*. Like I said, you can write a query now that will number your orders by month, you don't need to store those values on the table.

Comment: @DavidG I have to, 'cause these number are synchronized with external system. Let's say there were orders 1,2,3,4,5 in Jan. Orders 2 and 3 were created by accident, so that they were removed from the database. In such case order 4 and 5 should remain numbered as 4 and 5, but not become 2 and 3 as in your solution

Comment: @ZoharPeled there are no limitations not to do that

Comment: @McNets could you please provide a working example as an answer? also the snippet in the question is a working peace of code, so that IDENTITY certainly works

Comment: And you cannot synchronise using the actual Id column instead?

Comment: @AndreyPesoshin I always use another table for this purpose, something like 'SERIE varchar(), NumSeq int', and then I use a SP or UDF that looks for update, and returns the next number.

Comment: @DavidG no such option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple sequence can provide the auto-incrementing functionallity:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_numberInMonth as int START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order] (
    [Id]                INT             IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [NumberInMonth]     INT             NOT NULL DEFAULT(next value for seq_numberInMonth),
    [Amount]            DECIMAL (18, 2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Order] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Test:

```
INSERT INTO [Order] (Amount) VALUES (12.0), (13.0), (14.0)

SELECT *
FROM [Order]
```

results:

```
Id      NumberInMonth   Amount
1       1               12,00
2       2               13,00
3       3               14,00
```

You can quite easily [create a scheduled job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job) to run every 1st of the month and reset the sequence:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE seq_numberInMonth RESTART WITH 1 ;
```

Creating the job in t-sql can be done like this: (didn't test it, but it should work according to the following links):

[How to: Create a SQL Server Agent Job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153(v=sql.105).aspx)
[Create a Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job#a-nametsqlprocedureausing-transact-sql)

```
USE msdb ;  
GO  
EXEC dbo.sp_add_job  
    @job_name = N'seq_numberInMonth reset' ;  
GO  
EXEC sp_add_jobstep  
    @job_name = N'seq_numberInMonth reset',  
    @step_name = N'1st',  
    @subsystem = N'TSQL',  
    @command = N'ALTER SEQUENCE seq_numberInMonth RESTART WITH 1 ;',   
    @retry_attempts = 5,  
    @retry_interval = 5 ;  
GO  
EXEC sp_add_schedule @schedule_name =  'every 1st of the month' 
    , @enabled = 1
    , @freq_type = 16
    , @freq_interval = 1

GO  
EXEC sp_attach_schedule  
   @job_name = N'seq_numberInMonth reset',  
   @schedule_name = N'every 1st of the month';  
GO  
EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver  
    @job_name = N'seq_numberInMonth reset';  
GO
```